# How do I balance Laravel Horizon workers across multiple supvervisors

Tags: laravel-horizon

All was well having several queues managed by horizon under 1 supervisor (supervisor-1).  After moving 1 of the queues to supervisor-2, horizon is no longer processing jobs under supervisor-1.  Any ideas?

```
'defaults' => [
        'supervisor-1' => [
            'connection'      => 'redis',
            'queue'           => [
                'queue_1', 
                'queue_2', 
                'queue_3'
            ],
            'balance'         => 'auto',
            'balanceMaxShift' => 1,
            'balanceCooldown' => 1,
            'minProcesses'    => 3,
            'maxProcesses'    => 4,
            'memory'          => 192,
            // 'tries'           => 1,
            'nice'            => 0,
            'maxTime'         => 3600
        ],
        'supervisor-2' => [
            'connection'      => 'redis',
            'queue'           => [
                'queue_4'
            ],
            'balance'         => 'auto',
            'balanceMaxShift' => 5,
            'balanceCooldown' => 1,
            'minProcesses'    => 1,
            'maxProcesses'    => 10,
            'memory'          => 192,
            // 'tries'           => 1,
            'nice'            => 0,
            'maxTime'         => 3600
        ],
    ],
    'environments' => [
        'local' => [
            'supervisor-1' => [
                'balanceMaxShift' => 1,
            ]
        ]
    ],
```